# Beamer newline after quote

Tags: beamer, quotation

After a `quote` environment, Beamer fails to ensure text begins on a new line:[image]

Code:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 Quote:
 \begin{quote}
  Quoted.
 \end{quote}
 I quoted.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This seems like a bug: could anyone advise me how to fix it globally?   (Rather than, say, `\\` after all the `quote` environments which don't end at the end of a paragraph in the source file.)

Comment: The commit: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/509b1e2d7d97e68477be89ccc395bb382d064bcb is responsible for this change.

Comment: Thanks, @Raaja.  I've reproduced the difference before and after that commit.  (But I'm not skilled enough to see which bit of the new code is responsible.)

Comment: I made my comment on behalf of one of the experts in beamer. Therefore, I am also not qualified enough to differentiate the problem. So, may be we should wait until someone else answers this :)

Comment: On behalf of `samcarter`: "the implementation of the beamercolorbox was changed which has a few far reaching consequences. Amongst other things, a beamercolorbox is now smaller than the \textwidth, therefore there is enough space left on the line to fit a few small words like "I". As temporary solution I suggest to use https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josephwright/beamer/8f221c4cb8143780ea65a86d8942e9f6e6e25fa7/base/beamerbasecolor.sty and wait for the beamer maintainers to fix it."

Comment: Thanks, @Raaja (and ```samcarter```).  This seems to work, and not to destroy anything else in my slides.

Answer (score 1):

This was a temporary bug in beamer and has since been fixed.

Update to beamer version v3.57 or newer.